# Android java: Using a seekbar's progressValue correctly

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I am currently using a couple seekbars in my application. There are 2 that are giving me trouble. I have the maximum values of both these seekbars set to 10.

I will be using the value of the seekbars to alter 2 numbers in my code.

So basically, I have 2 variables that have a range. One is protein mod, and can be anywhere from 0.8 to 1.0, and fatmod that can be anywhere in between 0.3 and 0.6. I am taking the progressValue from the seekbar and converting that value to a percentage stored as a double, and then doing the equations

```
proteinmod = proteinmod = 0.8+(progressValue/10)*0.2;
fatmod = 0.3+(progressValue/10)*0.3;
```

**MY ISSUE:** The seekbars are only semi-functional. When all the way to the left, they are the minimum value of the range as expected - but remain that value until the seekbar is all the way maxed out, which then the proteinmod and fatmod are set to there max. I tried setting a textview equal to the progress value and testing it at various postions, and the progressValue is indeed working correctly. But for some reason these mod values will not assume a value anywhere else between the range I'd like. Here's my code. Thank you so much in advance!

```
double proteinmod = 0;
double fatmod = 0;

    seekbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
            proteinmod = 0.8+(progressValue/10)*0.2;
            tv6.setText(String.valueOf(proteinmod));
            updateOutput();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    seekbar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
            fatmod = 0.3+(progressValue/10)*0.3;
            tv6.setText(String.valueOf(fatmod));
            updateOutput();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I believe this should be all the code you need, but if you need other bits, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
proteinmod = 0.8+(progressValue/10d)*0.2;
```

and

```
fatmod = 0.3+(progressValue/10d)*0.3;
```

Since progressValue and 10 are both Integers the result of the division is an Integer. Casting 10 to a double should solve the problem.

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much! Fixed it exactly how I wanted.

I always thought if you did math with an integer and a double, the integer would be used in it's double counterpart. Thank you for clearing this up!